# How to call C++ class from C#

Tags: c#, c++, c++-cli

I suppose I have to create a managed C++ code to wrap the native C++. But I have the problem while trying to wrap an array used in function parameter whose type is defined in native C++. The native C++ code is as follows:

```
//unmanageCPP.h
class __declspec(dllexport) unmanageMoney
{
public:
    unmanageMoney(int a, int b) { rmb = a; dollar = b; }
    unmanageMoney() { rmb = 0; dollar = 0; }
    int rmb;
    int dollar;
};

class __declspec(dllexport) unmanageSum
{
public:
    //how to wrap this funciton?
    int addDollar(unmanageMoney a[], unmanageMoney b[]);
};

//unmanageCPP.cpp
#include "unmanaged.h"

int unmanageSum::adddollar(unmanageMoney a[], unmanageMoney b[])
{
    return a[0].dollar + b[0].dollar;
}
```

Could anyone tell me how to write the manageCPP.h? Thanks very much!

**Update**

I compose the manageCPP.h as follows, but I don't know how to write addDollar()

```
//first, I wrap the class unmanageMoney for use in manageSum::addDollar()
public ref class manageMoney
{
private:
    unmanageMoney* mMoney;
public:
    unmanageMoney getMoney()
    {
        return *mMoney;
    }
    manageMoney(int a, int b)   { mMoney = new unmanageMoney(a, b); }
    ~manageMoney()  { delete mMoney; }
};

public ref class manageSum
{
    // TODO: Add your methods for this class here.
private:
    unmanageSum *mSum;
public:
    manageSum()
    {
        mSum = new unmanageSum();
    }
    ~manageSum()
    {
        delete mSum;
    }

    //it must be wrong if I code like this, for unmanageSun::adddollar() only
    // receives unmanageMoney as arguments. So what should I do?
    int adddollar(manageMoney a[], manageMoney b[])
    {
            return mSum->adddollar(a, b);
    }

};
```

Comment: @CDBean If you have updates to your question or more details to provide, please edit your original question to include the new data.

Comment: You probably want `cli::array<manageMoney^> a` for your arguments to `addDollar`, this will show up in C# as `manageMoney[] a`.

Comment: For `unmanagedSum::adddollar`, are you sure you want `unmanagedMoney a[]` and not `const unmanagedMoney& a`? You appear to only want the first item in the array, which could be done with a reference (or pointer) instead.

Comment: @Ben Voigt  yeah, I found that, too. But what should do with the argument then? My current solution is to create another array whose type is unmanageMoney, and copy its value from   array<manageMoney^> ^a    . Is there a simpler way? By the way, what does '^' mean here?

Comment: @Jonathan Sampson   Thank you for reminding

Comment: @joel Rondeau  The code here is just an example. But I suppose reference or pointer has no difference from array. I use array here because I think array is more convenient to be wrapped.

Comment: @CDBean: `^` is a special pointer only found in C++/CLI.  It's a pointer to an object from the managed memory allocator, which is known to the garbage collector.  That's because the garbage collector has to update this pointer if it moves the object (and it has to know the object is still reachable).  Except for the interaction with the garbage collector, it works just like a normal pointer.  And there actually should be a top-level `^` on the array too, like `cli::array<manageMoney^>^ a`.  I forgot that on my first comment.

Answer (score 1):

You create a C++/CLI source file with

```
public ref class SomethingOrOther
{
    //...
};
```

and set the compile options to use the `/clr` option.

Beyond that, it's almost the same as writing native C++.  You'll `#include` the header file for the class you want to reuse, create instances and call their member functions, just the same as normal C++.  But anything inside that `ref class` will be visible to C#.

And you do NOT put `__declspec(dllexport)` on the class.  Not ever.  It's useful for functions, but creates misery when used with classes.

Comment: Thank you for answering, but what if the member function has the argument type defined in native C++ as well? Do I need to wrap the argument type, too?

Comment: @CDBean: Yes.  It doesn't always make sense to have a 1:1 mapping between native and managed types (sometimes it may make sense to split a struct parameter into multiple parameters or something like that), but you'll need to provide some form of conversion.

Comment: And I don't know why I shouldn't put __declspec(dllexport) on the class. I try deleting it, but it turns out wrong, with the error "missing module"